# repair mongodb database using pymongo

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

How can I repair a specific mongodb database using "pymongo", similar to "db.repairDatabase" shell command? My goal is to get the freed space back to OS after I drop a few collections in DB, which requires that I repair the DB. Thanks!

Comment: The `repair` command is not to be taken lightly. It is an administrative command, to be used by a database *administrator* who - forgive my french - knows the fun what he or she is doing.

Comment: Thanks, I'm not sure how that is helping, actually! Anyways, for other people wondering, the repair command is not directly exposed via pymongo, but can be executed using pymongo's "command" and passing "repairDatabase".

Answer (score 1):

Repair is not directly exposed via pymongo, but you can actually execute it using "command". In this particular case use:
 `db.command("repairDatabase")`

Comment: Which comes with quite some implications. First, the whole database will be locked. Second, for security reasons, you should have free disk space equal to your current data size + 2Gb. Third running the command will do a few things, including copying the documents back and forth and the indices are recreated. That can be a rather lengthy process *during which the database isn't reachable*. It is the *last* resort for reclaiming disk space IMHO. Forcing resyncs of replica set members needs no downtime and accomplishes the same thing. Even a temporary replica set does the trick without downtime.